# .click not working

Tags: jquery, class, click, hover

I'm trying to get the action when click and hover (margin-left + border-bottom) the .hover it's fine... but my .click doesn't work,  i tried this:

```
$(".border").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).switchClass( "border", "border_active", 500 );
        return false;
    }
    ,function(){
        $(this).switchClass( "border_active", "border", 400 );
        return false;
    }
);  
$(".border").click(
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('border');
        $(this).addClass('border_active')
    }
    ,function(){
        $(this).removeClass('border_active');
        $(this).addClass('border');
    }
);
```

but nothing, here's the hole code: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe6pE/13/, please show me the best way to get this working, Thanks

Comment: You are using `.border` as the selector for `.click`, but you are removing `.border` from within the function.  I believe that after removing `.border`, it's no longer binded to your click function.

Comment: Why do you need two separate functions inside the click? why not do toggleclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, just use `toggleClass`;

```
$('.border').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('border-active border');
});
```

This will just alternate the classes. If `border-active` is on to start with, then clicking it will turn `border-active` off and `border` on.

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('border-active border')`

Comment: +1 exactly what i answered (now deleted to vote yours up instead)

Comment: I tried $(this).toggleClass('border-active border'); but still not working. and i can't use border:hover cause actually this has a little animation that is not this exemple...
http://jsfiddle.net/Fe6pE/19/

Comment: @novoa that code seems buggy because of the sliding. It jumps around. But it still works. Hover > Move right. Click > stay right. Click > back to normal

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, `click()` does not take in 2 function arguments.

What you need to use instead is `mousedown()` and `mouseup()`

Or even better, you can avoid JavaScript and structure your CSS like:

```
.border {
    /* normal styles */
}
.border:hover {
    /* styles when hovered */
}
.border:active {
    /* styles when mouse is down */
}
```

Comment: There _is_ a deprecated version of `click` with multiple arguments. It alternates between the handlers. It's not an alias of `mousedown` `mouseup`

Comment: Correction: the multiple-handler version was called `toggle`, not `click`.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comments, just add toggleClass to it?

```
$(".border").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('border');
    $(this).toggleClass('border_active');
});
```

Comment: why not upvote the existing answer instead of adding duplicates ?